# Invalid format specifier for thousands place

Tags: python

I am trying to make a simple chart like output. Here are strings that I want to display:

a = "name", b = "10000.00", c = "code", d = "45.60", e = "30.00"

```
print("{0:20}${1:,20}{2:20}${3:,20}${4:,<5}".format(a,b,c,d,e),file=outfile)
```

I put "," to indicate thousands place in each format specifier in which I want them to be output as currency. It reports the error:

```
print("{0:20}${1:,20}{2:20}${3:20}${4:<5}".format(a,b,c,d,e),file=outfile)
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: is it possible you mean `.` where you use `,` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), width has to go after comma. Moreover, your `b` variable has to be a number (and not a string, as in your MWE):

```
>>> x = 10000.0
>>> '{0:20,}'.format(x)
'            10,000.0'
```

Comment: just like you said I put a comma after Width "${1:20,}". now error saying ValueError: Cannot specify ',' with 's'.

Comment: As it's stated in the answer, your variable has to be a number (either int or float) for the comma to work

Comment: I appreciate it